# How to create a responsive users list that can adjust when the window is stretched and compressed selecting the users with checkbox?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[The blue outline was supposed to go around the entire div(each user block)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzkAm.png):

[image]

[With Grid overlay for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGEsx.png):

[image]

This is the current output where the divs that contain the users profile picture, name and email are being overlapped by the div that follow them.

(This is a dummy code that is to be integrated in the project)

**This is the Code:**

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-width: 1160px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 150px);
  gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 10px;
  border: 5px solid purple;
}

.wrapper>.container {
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.Profile_image>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: plum solid;
}

.label {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
}

.checkBoxContainer {
  top: 50%;
  height: max-content;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
    </div>
    <div class="Profile_image">
      <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h1>
        <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**The Problem:**

I have a block (wrapper) of max-widht:1160px in which I want for all the users to be placed one besides another and if the number of users exceed the space then the remaining one should continue on the next line, if the window was to shrink in size then the list should adjust to the window length and form a single column where the user div is of minimum 200px and if the window is maximized then the number of users in the row should fill up the 1160px space.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/*
    used to remove default margins and padding, to ensure that spacing
    is consistent across browsers, and across the document; we also
    set box-sizing to use the border-box algorithm which includes any
    margins, and border-widths, in the assigned element-sizing:
*/
*,::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 100px auto;
  /*
    max-width: 1160px;
    I removed this declaration because while it set a max-width,
    it didn't set any other size constraints, whereas setting the
    width using the CSS clamp() function, allows us to set a minimum,
    preferred, and maximum size:
      width: clamp(<minimum size>, <preferred size>, <maximum size>);
    below, if the 90% of the parent element is less than 300px the
    element will take 300px in width; otherwise if 90% is greater than
    1160px the element will remain at 1160px; otherwise it will always
    occupy 90% of its parent's width:
  */   
  width: clamp(300px, 90%, 1160px);
  display: grid;
  /*
    this causes each new row of elements to occupy one fraction of
    the available space:
  */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  /*
    this was removed because while it set 5 columns those columns had
    no flexibility in sizing, and was always 5 columns regardless of
    available size:
      grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 150px);
    I replaced it with the following line; here we're still using the
    repeat() function, but the second argument is changed to use the
    minmax() function, this defines a size range greater than or equal
    to <min> and less than or equal to <max>:
      minmax(<min>, <max>);
    below this means that the columns will be at least 200px in size,
    and one fraction of the available space:
  */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  /*
    I combined these two functions together for simplicity, and
    for easier maintenance in future (if both values are in the
    same place, future you is more likely to see them both and
    adjust as necessary; I know they were on adjacent lines, but
    code has a habit of being changed unexpectedly):
      gap: 1rem;
      column-gap: 10px;
  */
  gap: 1rem 10px;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  /*
    I added this rule to give some space between the borders of the parent,
    and the child elements; I also copied the values for the gap property
    in order to maintain the visual spacing between columns and rows:
  */
  padding: 1rem 10px;
}

.wrapper > .container {
  /*
    setting the width here doesn't affect the track size,
    so it's easier to let the parent element's
    grid-template-columns() rule address the sizing
    (unless you specifically want the element to be smaller
    than the track size, which would be unusual):
      min-width: 200px;
  */
  display: flex;
  /*
    again, leave the sizing to the parent's grid-template-columns
    rule:
      width: 20%;
  */
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  background: #fff;
  /*
    as above, let the parent handle the gaps between grid-items;
    that's precisely what the gap property is for: 
      margin: 20px;
  */
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.Profile_image > img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: plum solid;
}

.label {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
}

.checkBoxContainer {
  top: 50%;
  height: max-content;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <!--
    <div class="container">
      <div class="checkBoxContainer">
        you had repeated ids in your code, because you obviously created
        one generic/anonymous example; but even in generic code repeated
        ids are invalid (though that leads to JavaScript errors, and if
        you use <label> elements with the "for" attribute that would
        also create problems):
        <input type="checkbox" id="uid">
      </div>
      <div class="Profile_image">
        <img src="/sub/Male.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        <h3>Troy</h1>
          <p class="email">troy@email.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  -->

  <!-- other than some layout differences, the HTML remains the same, with
       the exception of the changed ids, uid_1 through uid_7: -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_1"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_2"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_3"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_4"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_5"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_6"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="checkBoxContainer"><input type="checkbox" id="uid_7"></div>
    <div class="Profile_image"><img src="//picsum.photos/80/80" alt=""></div>
    <div class="label">
      <h3>Troy</h3>
      <p class="email">troy@example.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m9adwku1/).

References:

- [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self).
- [`auto-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat#auto-fit).
- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
- [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height).
- [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content).
- [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).
- [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax).
- [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-right).
- [`padding-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
- [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top).
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).